# Package javafx.embed.swing missing from JavaFX 12?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, java-12

I upgraded from Java 10 to Java 12 and JavaFX 12.

Now I can't compile my project anymore because `javafx.embed.swingSwingFXUtils` is no longer recognized.

Intellij can't find any library for the class. Seems like `javafx.embed` doesn't exist anymore.

I looked to see if the package was dropped but I couldn't find any information regarding it.

Comment: The `javafx.embed.swing` package is part of the `javafx.swing` module.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The module javafx.swing needs to be included in the gradle file:

```
javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.graphics', 'javafx.swing', 'javafx.base' ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, a file called **module-info.java** was generated in the same package.
There I had to add

```
requires javafx.swing;
```

When building again, the class was found.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it worked after I included javafx.swing dependency in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
```

check the version here
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-swing

Comment: Yay - no need for modules